# Core Data: Relationship ordered fetch

Tags: swift, core-data, entity, relationship

I am currently working on a workout app. I created 3 Core Data entities: routine, exercise and activity. I related routine and exercise with a many-to-many relationship.

My problem is that I want to display the exercises of a routine in a table view in the order the user created the routine. So if the user changes the order of the exercises, I have to save it in Core Data and fetch it accordingly, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Another problem is that I am not sure how to save the sets and repetitions of an exercise in my routine entity.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you will need a priority attribute then that contains the order of the exercises and that you also use to sort on when fetching.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What do you have working?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson can you explain it further?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I've got the code to fetch the exercises related to the routine and to present it in a table view, but it is not in the order the user created the routine.

Comment: Do you have a field/property on the exercise that holds the date/time they were created that you can use to sort by?

Comment: Since you want a sort order that is unrelated to the exercise itself and you want the user to be able to change that sort order then you need a specific attribute for this. When the user changes the order of the exercises this attribute needs to be updated for all exercises that are affected.